# Two qubit gate decomposition using Qiskit

Tags: programming, quantum-gate, qiskit, compiling

I am writing some python code to be able to optimise the total error in two qubit gate decomposition.

I am using the Qiskit module [qiskit.quantum_info.synthesis.two_qubit_decompose](https://qiskit.org/documentation/_modules/qiskit/quantum_info/synthesis/two_qubit_decompose.html#TwoQubitBasisDecomposer)

My question relates to the difference between the two classes given in this code. One is `TwoQubitWeylDecomposition` and seems to decompose using the `KAK1` method detailed on page two [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0507171.pdf).

The other, `TwoQubitBasisDecomposer()` allows you to input which specific two-qubit gate you want to use in the decomposition of an arbitrary `SU(4)` (e.g. `CNOT`, Molmer-Sorensen etc).

One of the methods of this class allows you to find the fidelity of a target unitary, using $0$, $1$, $2$ or $3$ implementations of the basis gate of your choice (higher fidelity with more basis gate usage). However, you have to turn the target unitary into the `TwoQubitWeylDecomposition` class, otherwise, you get errors (target doesn't have the attribute `.a`).

I'm uncertain why the target unitary needs to be a `TwoQubitWeylDecomposition` class. The [documentation](https://qiskit.org/documentation/_modules/qiskit/quantum_info/synthesis/two_qubit_decompose.html#TwoQubitBasisDecomposer) isn't very helpful either.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found why the target unitary needs to be a `TwoQubitWeylDecomposition` class as the `.a`, `.b`, and `.c` attributes allow for the access of the second `np.mod((d[:3]+d[3])/2, 2*np.pi)`. This argument is needed for the `TwoQubitBasisDecomposer()`, and so the target unitary needs to be a `TwoQubitWeylDecomposition`. I hope this helps. :)